# switch button with mysql update function

Tags: php, mysql, android-5.0-lollipop, android-switch

I am programming an app where the user can switch a toggle to "Ja" (engl. Yes) and "Nein" (engl. No) to start an activity (Training/Spiel). The layout works fine, the switch position gets saved when leaving activity or app.

But how can I implement a `MySQL` database update if a toggle is set to "Ja" or "Nein"? If the `switchSpiel` is positioned at "Ja", I want to execute

```
UPDATE users SET spiel_anmel = '$training' WHERE firstname ='$name'
```

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

```
public class Abmeldung extends Activity {
    Button zurueck;
    private TextView textViewSpiel;
    private TextView textViewTraining;
    private Switch switchSpiel;
    private Switch switchTraining;
    String firstname;
    String spiel_anmel;
    String spiel_anmel1;
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null;
    String line = null;
    int code;
    private String urlt = "http://hots/T.php";
    private String urls = "http://host/S.php";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.abmeldung);

    textViewSpiel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSpiel);
    switchSpiel = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchSpiel);
    textViewTraining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTraining);
    switchTraining = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchTraining);

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs1 = getSharedPreferences("SwitchSpiel", MODE_PRIVATE);
    switchSpiel.setChecked(sharedPrefs1.getBoolean("ValueSwitchSpiel", true));

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs2 = getSharedPreferences("SwitchTraining", MODE_PRIVATE);
    switchTraining.setChecked(sharedPrefs2.getBoolean("ValueSwitchTraining", true));

    zurueck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zurueck);
    zurueck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Abmeldung.this, Main.class));
        }
    });


    /**
     * Import Varbiable firstN aus SQlite für MySQl update
     **/
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    /**
     * Hashmap to load data from the Sqlite database
     **/
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    user = db.getUserDetails();

    final String firstN = user.get("fname");


// SPIEL
//set the Switch on
//switchSpiel.setChecked(true);
//attach a listener to check for changes in state
        switchSpiel.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked)
            {
                if (isChecked) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SwitchSpiel", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("ValueSwitchSpiel", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    textViewSpiel.setText("dabei!");
                    spiel_anmel1 = "Ja";

            } else
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SwitchSpiel", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("ValueSwitchSpiel", false);
                editor.commit();
                textViewSpiel.setText("nicht dabei :-(.");
                spiel_anmel1 = "Nein";

            }
        }
    });
    //check the current state before we display screen
    if (switchSpiel.isChecked()) {
        textViewSpiel.setText("dabei!");
    } else {
        textViewSpiel.setText("nicht dabei :-(.");
    }

    switchSpiel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            firstname=firstN.toString();
            spiel_anmel = spiel_anmel1.toString();

            switchSpiel();
        }
    });
// Training
//set the Switch on
//switchTraining.setChecked(true);
//attach a listener to check for changes in state
        switchTraining.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SwitchTraining", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("ValueSwitchTraining", true);
                editor.commit();
                textViewTraining.setText("am Start!!!");
            } else {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SwitchTraining", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("ValueSwitchTraining", false);
                editor.commit();
                textViewTraining.setText("eine faule Sau!");
            }
        }
    });

//check the current state before we display screen
    if (switchTraining.isChecked()) {
        textViewTraining.setText("am Start!!!");
    } else {
        textViewTraining.setText("eine faule Sau!");
    }
}


//Update MYSQL SPIEL (switchSpiel())

public void switchSpiel() {
    new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(urls, firstname, spiel_anmel);
}

private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //params comes from execute call: params[o] is the url
        try
        // Initializing parameters
        {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", urls[1]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("spiel_anmel", urls[2]));

            //Make HTTP Request
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            // Read the response

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

            // Return the response
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. Url may be invalid.";
        }
    }

} }
```

my `S.php`

```
$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

$name=$_REQUEST['firstname'];
$training=$_REQUEST['spiel_anmel'];

$flag['code']=0;

if($r = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET spiel_anmel = '$training' WHERE firstname ='$name'", $con)) {
    $flag['code']=1;
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
```

I update the java code because I have implemented two buttons for sending the switch position. Now i get a *org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of*.

```
public class Abmeldung extends Activity {
    Button zurueck;
    private TextView textViewSpiel;
    private TextView textViewTraining;
    private Switch switchSpiel;
    private Switch switchTraining;
    //String firstname;
    String spiel_anmel;
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null;
    String line = null;
    String username;
    String sa;
    int code;
    private String urlt = "http://.../insertA.php";
    private String urls = "http://.../insertB.php";


        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abmeldung);

        textViewSpiel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSpiel);
        switchSpiel = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchSpiel);
        textViewTraining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTraining);
        switchTraining = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchTraining);

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs1 = getSharedPreferences("SwitchSpiel", MODE_PRIVATE);
        switchSpiel.setChecked(sharedPrefs1.getBoolean("ValueSwitchSpiel", true));

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs2 = getSharedPreferences("SwitchTraining", MODE_PRIVATE);
        switchTraining.setChecked(sharedPrefs2.getBoolean("ValueSwitchTraining", true));

        zurueck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zurueck);
        zurueck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Abmeldung.this, Main.class));
            }
        });


        /**
         * Import Varbiable userid aus SQlite für MySQl update
         **/
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        /**
         * Hashmap to load data from the Sqlite database
         **/
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        user = db.getUserDetails();

        final String uname = user.get("uname");

// SPIEL
//set the Switch on
//switchSpiel.setChecked(true);
//attach a listener to check for changes in state
        switchSpiel.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SwitchSpiel", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("ValueSwitchSpiel", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    textViewSpiel.setText("dabei!");
                    spiel_anmel = "Ja";

                } else {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SwitchSpiel", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("ValueSwitchSpiel", false);
                    editor.commit();
                    textViewSpiel.setText("nicht dabei :-(.");
                    spiel_anmel = "Nein";

                }

            }

        });
        //check the current state before we display screen
        if (switchSpiel.isChecked()) {
            textViewSpiel.setText("dabei!");
        } else {
            textViewSpiel.setText("nicht dabei :-(.");
        }


// Training
//set the Switch on
//switchTraining.setChecked(true);
//attach a listener to check for changes in state
        switchTraining.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SwitchTraining", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("ValueSwitchTraining", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    textViewTraining.setText("am Start!!!");
                } else {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SwitchTraining", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("ValueSwitchTraining", false);
                    editor.commit();
                    textViewTraining.setText("eine faule Sau!");
                }
            }
        });

//check the current state before we display screen
        if (switchTraining.isChecked()) {
            textViewTraining.setText("am Start!!!");
        } else {
            textViewTraining.setText("eine faule Sau!");
        }

        //final String spielan = spiel_anmel;
        Button updates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updates);

        updates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sa = spiel_anmel.toString();
                username = uname.toString();
                updates();
            }
        });
    }


//UPdate MYSQL SPIEL (switchSpiel())

    public void updates() {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("spiel_anmel", sa));

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urls);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Adress",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader readers = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sbs = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = readers.readLine()) != null) {
                sbs.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sbs.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 2", "Error converting result "+ e.toString());
        }

        try {
            JSONObject json_datas = new JSONObject(result);
            code = (json_datas.getInt("code"));

            if (code == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Update Successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding php:

```
$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

$uname=$_REQUEST['uname'];
$spiel=$_REQUEST['spiel_anmel'];

$flag['code']=0;

if($r=mysql_query("UPDATE users SET spiel_anmel = 'spiel' WHERE uname LIKE 'uname'",$con))
{
    $flag['code']=1;
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/4193263). To fix this critical security hole, use Prepared Statements.

Comment: Thanks for the node...I know I should use mysqli instead of the old way. I will change it later. Focus is on the java code.